# Configuring Oracle Database Access in EF7

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, oracle, entity-framework-core

I'm following the Pluralsight course on [Building a Web App with ASP.NET 5, MVC 6, EF7 and AngularJS](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/aspdotnet-5-ef7-bootstrap-angular-web-app) and I'm having trouble configuring the Database connections to an exisiting Oracle Database.

The tool I'm using is [Visual Studio Code](http://code.visualstudio.com), scaffolding by [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io) and package dependencies by [NuGet](http://nuget.org) and [Bower](http://bower.io).

The tutorial assumes SqlServer is being used instead of Oracle, hence all the necessary configurations are aimed at it. I have looked EVERYWHERE for guidance, but sadly to no avail.

Right now my `project.json` file contains the following (trimmed):

```
"dependencies": {

  [...]

  "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
  "EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
  "EntityFramework.Oracle.Rdb": "7.3.4.0",
  "Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework": "12.1.2400",
  "OracleDbConnect": "1.0.0.0"
},
```

And my `config.json` contains the following:

```
"Data": {
        "WorldContextConnection" : "Server=;Database=TheWorldDb;Trusted_Connection=;MultipleActiveRecordSets=true"
    }
```

The tutorial specifies that the DataBase Context located in `WorldContext.cs` should contain a method overriding OnConfiguring as follows:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        var connString = Startup.Configuration["Data:WorldContextConnection"];
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connString);
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }
```

And finally, adding the Entity Framework service in the `startup.cs` file:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddScoped<TheWorld.Services.IMailService, TheWorld.Services.DebugMailService>();
    services.AddEntityFramework()
    .AddSqlServer()
    .AddDbContext<WorldContext>();
    
}
```

I need using those dependencies I imported to the project.json to configure the Oracle service and allow the Web Application to store and retrieve information from an exisiting Oracle database.

Is this even possible?

Many thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there is no Oracle provider for EF7, the package you use are for EF6.

Current providers are listed here: http://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/providers/index.html - but I would expect more to appear around the RTM of EF7 in Q1 2016

Comment: Thank you Erik. 
Does this mean that the solution would be to just downgrade the packages in the project.json to a version 6 of the Entity Framework and leave the Oracle packages as they are right now?